# Getting @future method complete before startTest()

Tags: unit-test, future

Is there a way to wait for all @future method completes before starting the test?

I think **Test.startTest()** does not wait for future methods. I need the future method to be done in order to setup data for my test case. And this question causes unexpected results in my test class.

Comment: Can someone tell me that it is impossible for waiting future methods done before Test.startTest()?........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. In testing, I believe that all of the async processes happen when you call Test.stopTest()

Comment: You might refer to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_test.htm): *All asynchronous calls made after the startTest method are collected by the system. When stopTest is executed, all asynchronous processes are run synchronously.*

Comment: I am talking about Test.startTest(). I would like to call some future method to setup testing data. But I can't make them complete before **starting** the test.

Answer (score 0):

Test.StartTest();
Test.StopTest();

1they reset your governor limits so you can test if your actual code is going to hit Limits.
2Test.StopTest(), actually forces your @future methods to run right now and return before progressing to the next step

@isTest
    private static void test_CalloutQueued()
    {
        // Setup my test data...
        FooController controller = new FooController();
        Test.StartTest();
        controller.save();
        Test.StopTest();
        // You can actually now assert that yes, it indeed was queued, 
        // and has run, and has returned data. Since this is a callout?

```
    System.assert(System.isFutureJobQueued('testFuture'));
}
```

Comment: I need to wait another future method between starttest and stoptest. That's why I need to wait for the future call finish before starttest...